# Mongoid: embeds_one through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've got a `Model1`, that embeds one `Model2`, which embeds one `Model3`. Is it possible to fetch a `Model1` instance by a `Model3` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to understand how `embeds_one` works. When you say:

```
embeds_one :model2
```

Mongoid does a few simple things:

1. Adds a `Hash` field called `model2`.
2. Wraps that embedded `Hash` in Mongoid so that it behaves like any other document.
3. Arranges to include the usual `_id` field in the embedded `Hash` and any other fields specified with `field`.

So you're really just working with a bunch of nested hashes and you query embedded documents like any other embedded hash:

```
Model1.where('model2.model3.some_field' => 11)
```